# texture formats in glTeximage3D

Tags: opengl, textures

I am using teximage3D with gl_texture_3D and gl_texture_2D_array as a targets.

I am creating 4 layers of colors and applying that on a sphere. So i am expecting that it will apply 4 layers on sphere equally.

But for GL_TEXTURE_3D, it repeats all the layers 2 times. whereas for gl_texture_2D_array it applies those layers only once as per expected.

```
int w = 4, h = 4, d = 4;
size_t size = w * h * d;

*format=GL_RGBA;
GLubyte *dataRGBA=new GLubyte[4*size];

for (int i=0; i<size/4; i++)
{
    dataRGBA[4*i]=200;
    dataRGBA[4*i+1]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+2]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+3]=255;
}

for (int i=size/4; i<size/2; i++)
{
    dataRGBA[4*i]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+1]=255;
    dataRGBA[4*i+2]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+3]=255;
}

for ( int i=size/2; i<(3*size)/4; i++)
{
    dataRGBA[4*i]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+1]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+2]=255;
    dataRGBA[4*i+3]=255;
}

for ( int i=(3*size)/4; i<size; i++)
{
    dataRGBA[4*i]=255;
    dataRGBA[4*i+1]=0;
    dataRGBA[4*i+2]=255;
    dataRGBA[4*i+3]=255;
}

glGenTextures(1,&id);
glBindTexture(*target11, id);
glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
// when this texture needs to be magnified to fit on a big polygon, use linear interpolation of the texels to determine the color
glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
// we want the texture to repeat over the S axis, so if we specify coordinates out of range we still get textured.
glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
// same as above for T axis
glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// same as above for R axis
glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);

glTexImage3D(*target11, 0, *format, w, h, d, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataRGBA);
```

Comment: Please provide more information, such as the actual texture coordinates you use. Also, 2D array textures and 3D textures have nothing to do with each other except for the function you use to upload image data. If you're trying to figure out which one to use, then you don't understand what they do very well.

Comment: @Nicol: Thanks for your reply.
I am using normalized texture coordinates for GL_TEXTURE_3D.
For 2D_ARRAY, i am taking s,t normalized and r as 0 to no of layers.
Actually i am loading obj file of a sphere. can you tell me how can i share with you obj file so that you can point me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that a 2d texture array uses integers as texture indices, while a 3d texture scales the R axis 0-1 like the S and T axes.

Comment: Also it would be nice to look at your texture coordinates and drawing code to see if that's the issue in this case.

Comment: that is not an issue as i am already taking texture coordinates as per specs i.e. normalized for 3D textures, integer for R axis and 0-1 for S T axes of array textures.